# JavaScript Not Woking inside Cordova Webview

Tags: javascript, android, html, cordova

I am trying to open android activity on html button click. This is not happening properly. I was using JavaScript for that.which is not working. My javascript is not getting called.

```
 public class WebViewActivity extends CordovaActivity{
        JavaScriptInterface JSInterface;
        @SuppressLint("SetJavaScriptEnabled")
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        super.init();
        setContentView(R.layout.webview);
        WebView wV = (WebView)appView.getEngine().getView();
        wV  =  (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView1);
        wV.addJavascriptInterface(new JavaScriptInterface(this), "JSInterface");
        System.out.println("Opening webview");
        wV.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/index.html" ); }
          public class JavaScriptInterface {
          Context mContext;

            /** Instantiate the interface and set the context */
            JavaScriptInterface(Context c) {
                mContext = c;
            }

            public void changeActivity()
            {
                Log.d("In webviewActivity", "Inside change activity");
                Intent i = new Intent(WebViewActivity.this, Google.class);
                startActivity(i);
                Log.d("After Intent", "Opening google class");
                finish();
            }
        }
 }
```

This is my html file from where my javascript calls inner class method

**index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
    <head>
        <script>


            function myFunction() {
                alert("Hiii");
                JSInterface.changeActivity();
            }
        </script>

    </head>
    <button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: `System.out.println` is not defined in the Javascript environment...

Comment: my javascript function myFunction () is not getting called.

Comment: Is there any error message?